# How to set button's anchor property dynamically?

Tags: delphi

I want to set `TBitBtn`'s anchor property dynamically.

First I have set the button's anchor as top right in design time. In that button click event I set form's `BorderStyle` as `bsDialog`. Then there should be a gap as shown in image. I want the button should be beside close button.

So I need to set button's left and its anchor as top right after assigning border style as `bsDialog`. Is it correct?

I don't know the way to change anchor property dynamically [image]

Thanks, Rakesh

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if I can see your problem. If it's about syntax then here you go:

```
  BitBtn1.Left:= 666;
  BitBtn1.Anchors := [akTop, akRight];
```

This is the way to modify position and anchor in code.

Comment: @TLama Code could still change the size. Or he is just experimenting, learning what you and I already know. Who knows.

Answer (score 10):

In Delphi FireMonkey (XE4) to set anchors dynamically you do:

```
Button1.Anchors := [TAnchorKind.akTop, TAnchorKind.akRight];
```