# How clone TChart in FMX

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, teechart

How do i clone a TChart at runtime?  I found [this link](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/clone-firemonkey-objects) but it is Delphi and i can't translate to C++ Builder.

Here is what i tried but i get an error at runtime of `Class TChart not found`:

```
TChart *tmp = new TChart(Chart1->Clone(this));
tmp->Parent = this->Panel2;
```

Also, how can i clone so that i can easily reference the new clones in code  - e.g. `Chart(2)`, `Chart(3)` etc.

**EDIT 1**:  I can clone a button with the following code, but i'm still getting the `Class TChart not found` when i try with a TChart.

```
TButton *tmp;
tmp = new TButton(Button1->Clone(this));
tmp->Parent=ToolBar1;  // put it on ToolBar1
tmp->Text = "Cloned Button";
```

**EDIT 2**:  The following code makes a chart clone and solved the `Class TChart not found` issue but it does not make a true clone. The image below shows Chart1 and the resulting clone (on Win32). My goal was to make a template chart (Chart1) and then just clone it as i needed new charts...without having to set gobs of properties to make it look like Chart1.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
RegisterClass(__classid(TChart));   
TChart* tmp =  (TChart*)(Chart1->Clone(Chart1));  // clone Chart1
tmp->Parent = Panel2;  // put the new clone on Panel2
tmp->Position->Y = 300;  
tmp->BottomAxis->Minimum = -8;
tmp->BottomAxis->Maximum = 8;
tmp->LeftAxis->Minimum = 0;
tmp->LeftAxis->Maximum = 10;
}
```

[image: Chart1 and its clone]

Comment: You could use the function `CloneChart`

Comment: Hi Kerem - i've been trying to use `CloneChart` but there seems to be some issues (i'm looking at the Steema user forums).  I can't get it to make a true clone.  I'll add "EDIT 2" to my original post so you can see what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TChart` component can be cloned with the function `CloneChart`.

```
TChart* tmp = new TChart(this);
CloneChart(tmp, Chart1, this, false);
tmp->Parent = this->Panel2;
```

You could save pointers to the created `TChart` objects in a vector.

Comment: Kerem - this works except the new chart is not anchored to the right like Chart1.  I can't figure out how to anchor it in C++ either.  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7832880/how-to-set-buttons-anchor-property-dynamically) shows how to do it in Delphi but can't figure how in C++.  I want to anchor it to left and right only.

Comment: Got it with `tmp->Align = TAlignLayout::Horizontal` after much searching.  [This link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Types.TAlignLayout) helped.